# how can i get SYN & SYN+ACK value for current tcp connection of any website on Browser?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, bash, tcp

As I know that

> '$sysctl | grep net.ipv4.tcp'

gives the system wide TCP parameter value,I need to make a script in Bash for my college practical file in which If we open Browser and input the URL such as **www.google.com** then SYN time of this connection establishment and SYN+ACK timing needed to take and compare with system wide  parameter to take the decision for delay and display a message about SYN and SYN+ACK?

Answer (score 0):

tcpdump will allow you to see the delta time between SYN and SYN/ACK which will give you initial RTT (assuming you are capturing from the client).

For example, `tcpdump -nS -s0 host www.google.com -ttt` shows the information you are looking for.

If you were wanting to extract only the initial round trip time automatically, one simple way (but not error proof), would be to redirect tcpdump output to a file and use grep and awk to extract only the delta time for SYN/ACK packets. For example:

1. `tcpdump -nS -s0 host www.google.com -ttt > /tmp/handshake.txt`
2. `cat /tmp/handshake.txt | egrep '\[S\.\]' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $1 }'`

The above commands could be added to a simple bash script to suit your requirements.

I'm not sure what you mean when talking about comparing to the "system wide parameter". There is no sysctl value that controls round trip time, it varies widely depending on which server you are talking too.

Comment: In my detail of question **system wide parameter** means what we have set for tcp parameter i.e 'ipv4.tcp_retries1=3' and 'ipv4.tcp_retries2=15' these  tcp retry value in my system now these are maximum retry attend if any failure in sending packet.And if there is tcp connection established and there is delay in receiving packet ,Can i able to see  on which try (such as 4rth attempt or 5th and so on ) this one delayed packet receive?